# Why do I have to send multiple messages to my Jabber bot before it will logout?

Tags: perl, xmpp, bots, instant-messaging

I am trying to make my own Jabber bot but i have run into a little trouble.  I have gotten my bot to respond to messages, however, if I try to change the bot's presence then it seems as though all of the messages you send to the bot get delayed.

What I mean is when I run the script I change the presence so I can see that it is online.  Then when I send it a message it takes three before the callback subroutine I have set up for messages gets called.  After the thirrd message is sent and the chat subroutine is called it still process the first message I sent.

This really doesn't pose too much of a problem except that I have it set up to log out when I send the message "logout" and it has to be followed by two more messages in order to log out.  I am not sure what it is that I have to do to fix this but i think it has something to do with iq packets because I have an iq callback set as well and it gets called two times after setting the presence.

Here is my source code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

#Libraries
use Net::Jabber;
use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;

#--------------- Config Vars -----------------
# Jabber Client
my $jbrHostname = "DOMAINNAME"; 
my $jbrUserName = "USERNAME";
my $jbrPassword = "PASSWORD";
my $jbrResource = "RESOURCE";
my $jbrBoss = new Net::Jabber::JID();
$jbrBoss->SetJID(userid=>"USERNAME",server=>$jbrHostname);

# MySQL
my $dbHostname = "DOMAINNAME";
my $dbName = "DATABASENAME";
my $dbUserName = "USERNAME";
my $dbPassword = "PASSWORD";
#--------------- End Config -----------------

# connect to the db
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$dbName;host=$dbHostname",$dbUserName, $dbPassword, {RaiseError => 1}) or die "Couldn't connect to the database: $!\n";

# create a new jabber client and connect to server
my $jabberBot = Net::Jabber::Client->new();
my $status = $jabberBot->Connect(hostname=>$jbrHostname) or die "Cannot connect ($!)\n";
my @results = $jabberBot->AuthSend(username=>$jbrUserName,password=>$jbrPassword,resource=>$jbrResource);

if($results[0] ne "ok")
{
    die "Jabber auth error @results\n";
}

# set jabber bot callbacks
$jabberBot->SetMessageCallBacks(chat=>\&chat);
$jabberBot->SetPresenceCallBacks(available=>\&welcome);
$jabberBot->SetCallBacks(iq=>\&gotIQ);

$jabberBot->PresenceSend(type=>"available");
$jabberBot->Process(1);

sub welcome
{
    $jabberBot->MessageSend(to=>$jbrBoss->GetJID(),subject=>"",body=>"Hello There!",type=>"chat",priority=>10);
    &keepItGoing;
}

$jabberBot->MessageSend(to=>$jbrBoss->GetJID(),subject=>"",body=>"Hello There! Global...",type=>"chat",priority=>10);
#$jabberBot->Process(5);
&keepItGoing;

sub chat
{
    print "Chat Called!\n";
    my ($sessionID,$msg) = @_;
    $jabberBot->MessageSend(to=>$msg->GetFrom(),subject=>"",body=>"Chatting!",type=>"chat",priority=>10);
    if($msg->GetBody() ne 'logout')
    {
        print $msg->GetBody()."\n";
        &keepItGoing;
    }
    else
    {
        &killBot($msg);
    }

}

sub gotIQ
{
    print $_[1]->GetID()."\n";
    &chat;
}

sub keepItGoing
{
    print "Movin' the chains!\n";
    my $proc = $jabberBot->Process(1);
    while(defined($proc) && $proc != 1)
    {
        $proc = $jabberBot->Process(1);
    }
}

sub killBot
{
    $jabberBot->MessageSend(to=>$_[0]->GetFrom(),subject=>"",body=>"Logging Out!",type=>"chat",priority=>10);
    $jabberBot->Process(1);
    $jabberBot->Disconnect();
    exit;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out what your title has to do with your question.

Comment: I don't know how to use the XMPP modules work with perl.  As I said above when I change the presence the messages it process seem to get put into a queue and they still get so it processes message #1 when in theory it should be processing #3, it process #2 when it should process #4, etc.

Comment: OK, you're using XMPP and Perl for this task. But your message doesn't demonstrate that XMPP and Perl are the problem. Maybe it's because of the way you're using `Net::Jabber`. Maybe it's something to do with buffered sockethandles or flaky queues or 100 other things. Someone might be able to explain to you "how XMPP modules work in perl" (as opposed to how every other module works in perl), but it's not clear to me that that would get you any closer to solving your problem. How about titling this "Why do I have to send my message 3 times before Jabber responds?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got resource starvation because of your keepItGoing routine.  In general, trying to use XMPP synchronously like this is not going to work.  I suggest getting your callbacks set up, then just calling Process() in **one** loop.

The docs for Process() say:

> ```
> Process(integer) - takes the timeout period as an argument.  If no
>                    timeout is listed then the function blocks until
>                    a packet is received.  Otherwise it waits that
>                    number of seconds and then exits so your program
>                    can continue doing useful things.  NOTE: This is
>                    important for GUIs.  You need to leave time to
>                    process GUI commands even if you are waiting for
>                    packets.  The following are the possible return
>                    values, and what they mean:
>
>                        1   - Status ok, data received.
>                        0   - Status ok, no data received.
>                      undef - Status not ok, stop processing.
>
>                    IMPORTANT: You need to check the output of every
>                    Process.  If you get an undef then the connection
>                    died and you should behave accordingly.
> ```

Each time you call Process(), 0 or more of your callbacks will fire.  You never know which, since it depends on server timing.  If you want for Process() to return before sending something, you're almost always thinking synchronously, rather than asych, which kills you in XMPP.

In your case, if you remove the call to keepItGoing from chat(), I bet things will work more like you expect.

Comment: @Joe Hildebrand: Can you possibly give or link to a similar example of what you are saying? I am having trouble visualizing the solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Joe Hildebrand: If I remove `keepItGoing` from `chat()` then how do I  get the script to run continuously until I send a message like "logout?"  I guess I am confused about how to make the bot "idle," I thought that was what I was achieving with the `keepItGoing` sub routine.  After implementing your suggestion my bot will eventually disconnect from the server because the script exits.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line:

```
$jabberBot->Process(1);
```

with these:

```
while (defined($jabberBot->Process(1))) {
    # Do stuff here
}
```